# How to align bootstrap 4, horizontal list group in center

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm using this snippet of code from [here](https://gist.github.com/danielflippance/d6401c926b4fb2442e15) (shown below)
to horizontally align items in a list group (in Bootstrap 4).

```
    .list-group.list-group-horizontal{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .list-group.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
        border-right-width: 0;
    }
    .list-group.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:first-child {
        border-top-right-radius:0;
        border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
    }
    .list-group.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius:4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:0;
        border-right-width: 1px;
    }
```

How can I center align the list group? I tried adding class `text-center` and some other things, however I did not succeed.

```
<div id="app" class="container my-container">

    <!-- Header -->
    <h2 class="text-center" >Sample Header</h2>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div class="list-group list-group-horizontal">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Categories</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Search</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/raelb/pen/JwJLqj)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**For posterity:**
Apply `d-flex justify-content-center` if your element is not a flex element.

**Original Answer:**
Apply `justify-content-center` to the `list-group`

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gZRzOR

Here it is in the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

```
<div class="list-group list-group-horizontal justify-content-center">
....
....
</div>
```

Comment: That works, however it seems `d-flex` is not necessary. Is `d-flex` needed?

Comment: You are right - It is not needed. It is required to make an element `display: flex` but in your case it already is.

Comment: @zer0: I suggest adding d-flex back in your answer... people who would use your answer in the future, would be misguided... they would only add "justify-content-center" class to their css and expect everything to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Justify content](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content), to change the horizontal placement of your elements:

```css
.list-group.list-group-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.list-group.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    border-right-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:first-child {
    border-top-right-radius:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius:4px;
}

.list-group.list-group-horizontal .list-group-item:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius:4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0;
    border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app" class="container">

    <!-- Header -->
    <h2 class="text-center" >Sample Header</h2>

    <!-- Buttons -->
    <div class="list-group list-group-horizontal d-flex justify-content-center">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">Categories</a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Search</a>
    </div>
</div>
```